# Resolve formatted table value in wix custom action

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer

I've created certificate wix extension (extension of IisExtension). This includes a custom table, which is consumed by a custom action.

A column is defined as follows:

```
<columnDefinition name="Account" type="string" length="72" 
   primaryKey="yes" modularize="property" category="formatted"
   description="..." />
```

This column contains values like "[Property]". When the custom action reads this column like this:

```
hr = WcaGetRecordString(hRecCertificate, vcpqAccount, &pwzTemp);
```

it get's the string "[Property]". But I need "PropertyValue". How can this string be resolved?

Regards Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WcaGetRecordFormattedString is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've not really used WcaGetRecrodString. Take a look at the [MsiFormatRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370109%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.  Check the return code and read all the gotchas on MSDN for tips on what might be going wrong.